# Saving images to ImageField that are crawled by a background task

Tags: python, django

I have a program running in the background that will output images to a specific folder on my server, and this can happen at different intervals. I need to be able to show these images on a template, so I want to save them to the db using `ImageField`.

My question is how would I go on saving them to the DB? Can I just do something along `os.listdir(dir)` on a background task and save that directly to the DB, or does it need the full path to the image?

I have already created the Model for this

```
class Usertasks(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="missing")
```

```
class TaskImages(models.Model):
    UserTasks = models.ForeignKey(Usertasks, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: Have you ever worked with Jupyter Notebooks and seen how they connect to django to make the calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just iterate through your directory and save each file to the model:

```
from django.core.files import File

with open('path_to_file', 'rb') as f: 
    data = File(f)
    TaskImages.image.save('filename', data, True)
```

Perhaps what's trickier is when are you going to invoke this save, and how ofter are you going to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, os
print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))

import django
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())

sys.path.append('<path to your project>')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'PROJECTNAME.settings')
if 'setup' in dir(django):
   django.setup()
print('Django Start!')

...
Imagine you are in a view and make your normal script, 
generating the images and    saving them to templates.
...
```

See if you can understand the code above, you will basically start it and you will be able to load all the necessary templates. I usually work with code like this in scripts and in the same directory as manage.py.

PS: Obviously you can remove the prints, I leave because in Jupyter helps me to visualize when the notebook stops working.